# enable vbscript to run in both command line and by double click

Tags: vba, vbscript

I have the following vbscript which works perfectly fine when run in the command line. Would love to incorporate this to work with the windows GUI when double clicked with a mouse.

**Current Setup**

Here is the current command to execute the vbscript - requires two arguments

1. filename
2. password

`cscript fix.vbs file.ext password`

Here is my code (fix.vbs):

```
Dim Arg, pfxFileName, keyFileName, cerFileName, cabFileName, keyPassword
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments

pfxFileName = Arg(0)
keyPassword = Arg(1)
keyFileName = "key.tmp"
cerFileName = "cer.tmp"
cabFileName = "cabundle.tmp"

Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
return = oShell.run("cmd /C openssl pkcs12 -in " & pfxFileName & " -nocerts -out " & keyFileName & " -passin pass:" & keyPassword & " -passout pass:" & keyPassword & " | openssl pkcs12 -in " & pfxFileName & " -clcerts -nokeys -out " & cerFileName & " -passin pass:" & keyPassword & " | openssl pkcs12 -in " & pfxFileName & " -cacerts -nokeys -out " & cabFileName & " -passin pass:" & keyPassword, 0, true)

' strip all ca's except for the last block
Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim reCut : Set reCut = New RegExp
reCut.Global = True
reCut.Pattern = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----[\s\S]+?-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
Dim oMTS : Set oMTS = reCut.Execute(goFS.OpenTextFile(cabFileName).ReadAll())
Dim sBlock : sBlock = oMTS(oMTS.Count - 1).Value
' WScript.Echo sBlock

Sub SaveStringToFile(filename, text)
    Dim fso, f
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 2)
    f.Write text
    f.Close
End Sub

SaveStringToFile cabFileName, sBlock

' build pfx file
return = oShell.run("cmd /C openssl pkcs12 -export -in " & cerFileName & " -inkey " & keyFileName & " -certfile " & cabFileName & " -out NEW-" & pfxFileName & " -password pass:" & keyPassword & " -passin pass:" & keyPassword, 0, true)

Dim WshShell, strCurDir
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCurDir    = WshShell.CurrentDirectory
WScript.Echo vbNewLine & ">>> Thew NEW PFX file is located in " & strCurDir & "\" & "NEW-" & pfxFileName

Set oShell = Nothing

' remove files
Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
obj.DeleteFile(cerFileName)
obj.DeleteFile(keyFileName)
obj.DeleteFile(cabFileName)
```

**Required additions**

1. Make the above mentioned code compatible to work when double clicked
   in windows GUI.
2. Prompt the user to enter two arguments (browse to file) & (file
   password)

Comment: So what is your question? Check to see if you have values in `Arg(0)` and `Arg(1)`; if you don't, you're running from being double-clicked and you prompt for the values. How else would you expect to get them from a double-click?

Comment: i suppose that makes sense.. the way its written now is the arguments can only passed by the command line.

Comment: The only way you can provide them with a double click (without prompting for them) would be to hard-code them into the script, which doesn't seem to suit the requirements you've described. A suggestion: For future questions, you should make an effort to actually state the question you're asking. This one did not, but reading between the lines was easy. Future questions may not fare so well, and downvotes pile up quickly on poorly asked questions.

Comment: no, I do wish to prompt when double clicked. Sorry if I wasn't clear about that. I will update the post to be crystal clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a .vbs file with below code and place it at desktop. Double click it.

```
    PerformAction

Private Sub PerformAction()

  pfxFileName = Trim(InputBox("Enter Filename:", "My VB Script"))
  If pfxFileName = vbNullString Then
    Exit Sub
  End If

  keyPassword = Trim(InputBox("Enter Password:", "My VB Script"))
  If keyPassword = vbNullString Then
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ProcessCertificate pfxFileName, keyPassword

End Sub

Private Sub ProcessCertificate(ByVal pfxFileName, ByVal keyPassword)
  Dim keyFileName, cerFileName, cabFileName
  keyFileName = "key.tmp"
  cerFileName = "cer.tmp"
  cabFileName = "cabundle.tmp"

  Dim oShell
  Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  return = oShell.run("cmd /C openssl pkcs12 -in " & pfxFileName & " -nocerts -out " & keyFileName & " -passin pass:" & keyPassword & " -passout pass:" & keyPassword & " | openssl pkcs12 -in " & pfxFileName & " -clcerts -nokeys -out " & cerFileName & " -passin pass:" & keyPassword & " | openssl pkcs12 -in " & pfxFileName & " -cacerts -nokeys -out " & cabFileName & " -passin pass:" & keyPassword, 0, true)

  ' strip all ca's except for the last block
  Dim goFS: Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim reCut: Set reCut = New RegExp
  reCut.Global = True
  reCut.Pattern = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----[\s\S]+?-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
  Dim oMTS: Set oMTS = reCut.Execute(goFS.OpenTextFile(cabFileName).ReadAll())
  Dim sBlock: sBlock = oMTS(oMTS.Count - 1).Value
  ' WScript.Echo sBlock

  SaveStringToFile cabFileName, sBlock

  ' build pfx file
  return = oShell.run("cmd /C openssl pkcs12 -export -in " & cerFileName & " -inkey " & keyFileName & " -certfile " & cabFileName & " -out NEW-" & pfxFileName & " -password pass:" & keyPassword & " -passin pass:" & keyPassword, 0, true)

  Dim WshShell, strCurDir
  Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  strCurDir = WshShell.CurrentDirectory
  WScript.Echo vbNewLine & ">>> Thew NEW PFX file is located in " & strCurDir & "\" & "NEW-" & pfxFileName

  Set oShell = Nothing

  ' remove files
  Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  obj.DeleteFile (cerFileName)
  obj.DeleteFile (keyFileName)
  obj.DeleteFile (cabFileName)
End Sub

  Sub SaveStringToFile(filename, text)
      Dim fso, f
      Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, 2)
      f.Write text
      f.Close
  End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this. I tried to run this but i get an error on Line 38, Char 3, Code: 800A03EA.

Also, will this code work with both command line and windows GUI as requested?

Comment: There was a procedure inside, which I moved it out and updated the code above. Try using it. I cannot compile on my machine as I do not have openssl and other required stuff. Intention is to show you the use of inputbox to read userinput and pass it to a function. this can be used on double click.

Comment: works great now! i would just ask for when prompting to enter the file name is it possible to have a 'Browse' button instead of manually typing in the file? although, i realize doing this might break the code because i am not factoring in paths.. the current code assumes the file is in the same directory as the script.

Comment: Browse button not possible with input box. You can refer the reference of InputBox and can provide default values. This will minimize typing full path input to input box. If code is working fine, I hope this is what you are looking for, so plz mark it as solved/answered.